# Why do 'neutral' parenthesis cause errors in R (or maybe the tidyverse)?

Tags: r, dplyr

When I have large complicated chunks of code I'll often use more parenthesis sets than are required. My code could look like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(name = rownames(.)) %>% 
  filter((cyl == 4 & grepl("Toyota", name)) | 
           ((cyl == 6 | cyl == 8), grepl("Mazda", name)))
```

instead of this:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(name = rownames(.)) %>% 
  filter(cyl == 4 & grepl("Toyota", name) | 
           (cyl == 6 | cyl == 8, grepl("Mazda", name)))
```

What can I say? In my head the *parenthesis protection* helps me see De Morgan's laws easier, PEMDAS easier, computational order, etc.

This liberal use of parenthesis presents a problem. Even though I would think extra parenthesis should be neutral in R and the tidyverse, they appear not to be. Look at the error I get in the code chunk below.

```
mtcars %>% filter((cyl == 4 & am == 1)) %>% .[1, 3]
# [1] 108
mtcars %>% filter((cyl == 4, am == 1)) %>% .[1, 3]
# Error: unexpected ',' in "mtcars %>% filter((cyl == 4,"
```

Why does the first example directly above work, and the second throws an error? I know the direct answer is "you're using too many parenthesis" but why can't I? It just makes life easier, for me, in these logical operator nest nightmares. I am aware of the `case_when()` function which does help in these type of circumstances. I still want to know why I can't use extra parenthesis though. Thank you.

Comment: The dplyr team already knows the tradeoffs of implementing this feature, right? How silly is it for me to put in a feature request to remove this feature? I'm sure the cost/benefits have been weighed, and determined to be worth it. Actually I'm not sure, and so I comment here.

Comment: I would be surprised if they haven't considered it internally a least a fair bit. It's a convenience feature for simple cases, which is great, the downside is just that it can be hard for people to figure out on their own when they've outgrown the simple solution and need to be more explicit.

Comment: Most functions don't work this way though. You can't add arbitrary parenthesis to base functions either. For example `runif(1,2,3)` works but `runif((1,2,3))` does not. When not used in a call syntax (actually calling a function) parentheses needs to contain valid expressions.  Values separated by commas are not a valid expression in R. In order to pass values as separate parameters to a function, they cannot be nested inside parenthesis.

Comment: @MrFlick in that case is `(cyl == 4 & am == 1)` a valid expression, when it is used with the `dplyr::filter()` function, or does it need to be `cyl == 4 & am == 1` in order to be a valid expression? Without parenthesis my complicated boolean operations are very hard to visually look at and comprehend.

Comment: Yes. `cyl == 4 & am == 1` is a valid expression. if you defined the variables `cyl<-1` and `am<-1` you can run that line at the console without error. But you cannot run `cyl == 4 , am == 1`

Comment: @MrFlick so as long as the included expression is valid, I can surround this inside expression in as many parenthesis as I please? Is that correct? It appears so because this code works: `cyl <- 1; am <- 1; (((((cyl == 4 & am == 1)))))  # [1] FALSE`

Comment: Yes. When not used to pass parameters to a function, the parenthesis are like their own function that just rerun the value of the expression they contain. So nesting them in that context is fine. They are kind of like braces but can only contain a single expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using a "feature" of filter that conditions passed into `...` and separated by commas are "automagically" joined with an `&`. But the parsing magic that makes that work isn't smart enough to sees through a single set of parens.

So it see just one condition, `cyl == 4, am == 1` which isn't really syntactically valid as a single boolean expression. This is one of the reasons why I rather dislike this feature and always write out the `&`'s.

I suspect that since this feature of `filter` is fairly complicated to implement, there's not much benefit in trying to get it to parse the conditions in a more recursive manner. The perhaps unsatisfying answer is that passing conditions separated by commas is fine if you are doing something very simple, but if your boolean condition is complicated you should be more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

What MrFlick has commented is the main reason for your problem,
but there is still some inconsistency in your example.
We can use the `rlang` package to see what `dplyr` does with your input,
which by the way isn't really magic,
it's just using R's standard features for non-standard evaluation
(R does have to parse your code after all).

First the expression that was given to `filter` without extra parentheses:

```
library(rlang)

exprs(cyl == 4 & grepl("Toyota", name) | 
        (cyl == 6 | cyl == 8), grepl("Mazda", name))
[[1]]
cyl == 4 & grepl("Toyota", name) | (cyl == 6 | cyl == 8)

[[2]]
grepl("Mazda", name)
```

So after joining everything with `&` you do get the expression that you want,
but what's important is to note that you get 2 expressions because the comma separated them,
and `filter` will parse each separately using standard R rules.
You could write the expression like this for clarity:

```
exprs(cyl == 4 & grepl("Toyota", name) | (cyl == 6 | cyl == 8), 
      grepl("Mazda", name))
```

If you add the extra parentheses,
`filter` would see a single expression with everything you wrote.
If R tried to parse that expression,
it would see (after removing the parentheses):

```
cyl == 4 & grepl("Toyota", name) | (cyl == 6 | cyl == 8), grepl("Mazda", name)
```

Which, like MrFlick said, is not valid in R.

Comment: and following joran's advice I could always use `&` instead of `,` and I would have ended up with the valid expression: `cyl == 4 & grepl("Toyota", name) | (cyl == 6 | cyl == 8) & grepl("Mazda", name)` instead of the invalid expression `cyl == 4 & grepl("Toyota", name) | (cyl == 6 | cyl == 8), grepl("Mazda", name)`. Is that correct?